# What do the colors mean in dnf repository-packages <repoid> list?

Tags: dnf

What do the colors mean in dnf repository-packages  list?

In my case, in the "`Installed Packages`" section of the output of
`dnf repository-packages appstream list`
the colors of the the two entries below seem to match my vim colorscheme (desert). Most entries are aqua-ish (matching comments) and others are brownish (matching constants and commands like if, else and echo).

firefox.x86_64
java-11-openjdk-headless.x86_64

Thinking it might be a case of whether I installed them dnf or another way, I checked with dnf and neither are in the dnf history for installs.

java appears in dnf for an update
( I believe it was installed as part of libreOffice as it has no "install" entry in dnf history )

Answer (score 0):

after updating firefox its color changed from brownish to aqua-ish
so,

dnf repository-packages  list colors represent the update status